# Unique constraint that allows empty values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraints

I have a field that stores product codes. The codes are unique, but some products simply doesn't have a code. I can't invent codes because those are providers codes.

Is this kind of constraint possible in MySQL?

I'm a noob with stored procedures and triggers, so if the solution involves one of these, please be patient.

Update:
The column is NOT Null. That's why I was unable to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MySQL ignore null values on unique constraints?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712222/does-mysql-ignore-null-values-on-unique-constraints)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. See the [MySQL reference (version 5.5)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a key value that matches an existing row. For all engines, a UNIQUE  index allows multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL.

Comment: Thanks. I have to make it nullable

Comment: had this problem in django model . Making it nullable works. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Yes, if you make the product code column nullable (not declared with `NOT NULL`), the unique key will allow multiple rows with `NULL` product codes.

Comment: Thanks. I have to make it nullable

Answer (score 8):

MySQL still allows for multiple rows to have a value of `NULL` in a unique column.

Comment: Thanks. I have to make it nullable

Comment: @MianAnjum bolded: CREATE TABLE `table` (`key` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `field` tinyint(1) **DEFAULT NULL**)