# Mysql Unique Index on Multiple Fields when FieldX = 1

Tags: mysql

*Scenario : Multiple product images, one main image.*

Currently, I've got 2 tables to manage this. One for storing product images and another table for storing `mainProductImageIds`. In the table that stores a list of `mainProductImageIds`, I've got a unique index on `prodid`+`isMain` to enforce **One Main Image Per Product Id**.

***My Question*** relates to the table below (if I was going to only use 1 table). How would I enforce 1 `isMain=1` per `prod`? Is there any index setting that would error when I tried to set `isMain=1` to `image_id=2` since `image=1` is already the main image? You can't put a unique_key on `prod`+`isMain`.

```
|image_id |prod|isMain
|---------|----|------
|0        |1   |0
|1        |1   |1
|2        |1   |0
|3        |2   |1
|4        |3   |0
|5        |3   |1
```

Comment: Would be simple with other DBMS (that support partial indexes), but I can't think of an easy solution in MySQL.

Comment: It should be possible to do this using a trigger on insert/update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, I learned, is really simple and has to do with how MySQL indexes NULL values. [Over Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346765/unique-constraint-that-allows-empty-values-in-mysql) they talk about:

> For all engines, a UNIQUE index allows multiple NULL values for
>   columns that can contain NULL.

so as long as my `isMain` field allow enforces one value and NULL (maybe an ENUM), I'm all set. The unique_index will only be enforces when isMain is set to a distinct value and not when it is set to NULL.

**The Updated Table Looks like This:**

```
|image_id |prod|isMain
|---------|----|------
|0        |1   |null
|1        |1   |1
|2        |1   |null
|3        |2   |1
|4        |3   |null
|5        |3   |1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do this with a `TRIGGER`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_unique BEFORE UPDATE ON `images`
    FOR EACH ROW
        SET NEW.isMain = IF(NEW.isMain = 0, 0,
            CASE WHEN ( SELECT MAX(isMain) FROM images AS q WHERE q.prod = NEW.prod ) = 1
            THEN NULL ELSE NEW.isMain END);
```

or, faster (especially if indexed)

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_unique BEFORE UPDATE ON `images`
    FOR EACH ROW
        SET NEW.isMain = IF(NEW.isMain = 0, 0,
           IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM images AS q WHERE q.prod = NEW.prod AND q.isMain = 1), NULL, 1));
```

This will allow setting isMain to 0 always; if you want to set it to 1, then it will check that there are no other rows for the same product for which isMain is 1.

### Example

In the example below, I cannot set `isMain = 1` where `prod=3` until I set `isMain=0` on the other image which had `isMain = 1`.

```
CREATE TABLE images (
   image_id integer not null primary key auto_increment, 
   prod integer not null,     isMain integer not null );

INSERT INTO images VALUES (1, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (3, 2, 0), (4, 2, 1);

select * from images;
+----------+------+--------+
| image_id | prod | isMain |
+----------+------+--------+
|        1 |    1 |      0 |
|        2 |    1 |      1 |
|        3 |    2 |      0 |
|        4 |    2 |      1 |
+----------+------+--------+

CREATE TRIGGER check_unique BEFORE UPDATE
    ON `images` FOR EACH ROW
       SET NEW.isMain = IF(NEW.isMain = 0, 0, IF (EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM images AS q WHERE q.prod = NEW.prod AND q.isMain = 1), NULL, 1));

UPDATE images SET isMain = 1 WHERE image_id = 3;
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'isMain' cannot be null

UPDATE images SET isMain = 0 WHERE image_id = 4;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

UPDATE images SET isMain = 1 WHERE image_id = 3;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1
```

You could extend this approach so that you can always set to 1 the isMain of any row... *but the row that was isMain before for that product gets zeroed*.

Comment: check out the solution I found to enforce it without triggers. Your update statements would apply to both solutions.

Comment: Yes, but I think the `NULL` trick it's less portable (it only works if there is *one* value you "don't want"), and less clean data-wise; you end up with two different data types, one `NULL`. That said, it *will* work, and it *will* be much faster!

Comment: well, in this case, i only need to worry about that 1 value.. isMain. And it being much faster is always a good thing. Thank you for being so helpful @Iserni !