# MySQL Unique constraint for Column does not allow insert multiple Null and empty. ENGINE=InnoDB

Tags: mysql

With `SHOW CREATE TABLE` get following information

```
 (      
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyName` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RegistrationNumber` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,

   UNIQUE KEY `Number_2` (`Number`),
   UNIQUE KEY `CompanyName` (`CompanyName`),
   UNIQUE KEY `RegistrationNumber` (`RegistrationNumber`)

 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=280 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

In `RegistrationNumber` need to allow insert multiple NULL and empty values.

However get error `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'RegistrationNumber'`

Here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,53591,53591 read that for InnoDB NULL is not treated as unique value.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346776/2465936 read that Unique constraint allows empty values.

Please, advice how to insert multiple empty values in `RegistrationNumber` Do I need to change something in `RegistrationNumber varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,`?

Or with `ENGINE=InnoDB` it is not possible? Changed to MyISAM. The same error...

**Update**

Oh.... going crazy

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 18_6_TransactionPartners (RegistrationNumber) VALUES";

$insertQuery = array();
$insertData = array();

foreach ($num_row_1 as $i => $row) {
$insertQuery[] = '(?)';

if ( (strlen($data_b[$i])) > 0 ) {
echo '(strlen($data_b[$i])) > 0<br>';
$insertData[] = $data_b[$i];
}
else {
echo '??? null??? <br>';
$insertData[] = 'NULL';
}
}
```

And get `QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'NULL' for key 'RegistrationNumber'`

What is wrong now?

Needed to change `$insertData[] = 'NULL'` to `$insertData[] = NULL;`

Finally all is clear. Thanks for answers

Comment: `null` isn't the same as empty string or `0`. a `null` is `null`. Period. If you have such a constraint, enter `null` value, not empty or 0 because they produce constraint failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It should work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c876/2) as you say.

But it looks like you insert an empty string and not null into your column. That is different. You can't have multiple empty strings in a unique column.

`0` is not `null`. `0` is a value - zero. But `null` means **no** value.

Comment: I tried to insert multiple `0` and get `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key RegistrationNumber`. I trying to import excel file content in mysql

Comment: `0` is not `null`. `0` is a value - zero. But `null` means **no** value.

Comment: Thanks. Will experiment (to understand)... seems starting to understand. If want to insert multiple `NULL` then can insert. If multiple ` ` or `0`, can not insert. So, see solution that empty string and `0` need to convert to `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

A `Unique Constraint` allows multiple `Null` values. In database context, *empty value* really means `Null`, since the *empty string* (or number zero etc) are perfectly known values.
What you can do is use the [`NULLIF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and replace the empty strings with null (i.e. `Nullif(myValue,''`)