# MariaDB/MySQL composite unique index not effective

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

Situation: I've created unique composite index over table, which took some time, didn't delete duplicite records and doesn't prevent me from inserting duplicate rows.

Anybody knows what is going on in here?

Table structure:

```
> DESCRIBE translations;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| text        | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| language_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| parent_id   | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| flag        | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Index creation:

```
> ALTER IGNORE TABLE `translations`
ADD UNIQUE `unique_translations`
(`language_id`, `parent_id`, `type`, `flag`);

Query OK, 12225526 rows affected (4 min 51.91 sec)     
Records: 12225526  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Indexes listing:

```
> SHOW INDEXES FROM `translations`;
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| translations |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id          | A         |    12178547 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          0 | unique_translations |            1 | language_id | A         |        2712 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          0 | unique_translations |            2 | parent_id   | A         |     2435709 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          0 | unique_translations |            3 | type        | A         |     2435709 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          0 | unique_translations |            4 | flag        | A         |     3044636 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          1 | language_id_fk      |            1 | language_id | A         |          26 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          1 | parent_id_fk        |            1 | parent_id   | A         |     1522318 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          1 | flag                |            1 | flag        | A         |       10562 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| translations |          1 | type                |            1 | type        | A         |       30370 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Verification of problem:

```
> SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `translations`;
+-------------+
| COUNT(`id`) |
+-------------+
|  12225526   |
+-------------+
1 row in set (3.29 sec)

> SELECT * FROM `translations` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1;
+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| id       | text           | language_id | parent_id | type         | flag        |
+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| 13754252 | text           |          50 |      NULL | text2        | text3       |
+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

> INSERT INTO `translations` VALUES (NULL, "text", 50, NULL, "text2", "text3");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

> SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `translations`;
+-------------+
| COUNT(`id`) |
+-------------+
|  12225527   |
+-------------+
1 row in set (2.19 sec)
```

Machine info:

```
root@precise64:~# uname -a
Linux precise64 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@precise64:~# dpkg -l | grep -i mariadb
ii  libmariadbclient18                  10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        MariaDB database client library
ii  mariadb-client-10.0                 10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-10.0            10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                      10.0.14+maria-1~precise          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
ii  mariadb-server                      10.0.14+maria-1~precise          all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-server-10.0                 10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
ii  mariadb-server-core-10.0            10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        MariaDB database core server files
ii  mysql-common                        10.0.14+maria-1~precise          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
root@precise64:~# dpkg -l | grep -i mysql  
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                   4.025-1                          amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient18                    10.0.14+maria-1~precise          amd64        Virtual package to satisfy external depends
ii  mariadb-common                      10.0.14+maria-1~precise          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
ii  mysql-common                        10.0.14+maria-1~precise          all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
ii  php5-mysql                          5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5            amd64        MySQL module for php5
rc  php5-mysqlnd                        5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11               amd64        MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
ii  phpmyadmin                          4:4.0.10-1                       all          MySQL web administration tool
root@precise64:~#
```

Comment: Do you still have a copy of the table  before you imposed the unique index on it?  If so, please try `SELECT COUNT(*), language_id, parent_id, type, flag FROM original_translations GROUP BY language_id, parent_id, type, flag HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.  This will identify any duplicates that your unique index would prohibit.

Comment: @OllieJones this query returns 759 rows of 12.234.849 total, which is suspicious to me, because I can see more duplicates browsing the data by hand.

Comment: @OllieJones and part of the returned rows are not duplicates, at least flag column usually differs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a multi-column unique index on the following four columns, the following records would all be allowed and would not be considered duplicates:

```
language_id | parent_id | type         | flag
------------------------------------------------------
         50 |         1 | text2        | text3
         50 |      NULL | text2        | text3
         50 |      NULL | text2        | text3
         50 |         1 | text2        |  NULL
```

Remember that `NULL` means *unknown*. Though `NULL` values are indexed, any value compared to NULL returns NULL. In order for values to be considered duplicate, they must past the equality test, yet:

```
1 != NULL
NULL != NULL
```

Comment: NULL isn't considered unique value, that explains it. So only solution is to not allow these columns to be NULL, or is there different solution? I'm trying to avoid solutions that require change on application level (which changing nullable and/or default value of column is). Thank you

Comment: How do you know they're duplicates unless the value is filled in (non-null)? Perhaps you mean to use 0 instead of NULL?

Comment: It's b-tree, so NULL in parent_id means it's parent element, flags are optional and there should be allowed only one row with unique combination (language_id,parent_id,type) and (flag).

Comment: Unfortunately, you should not have used NULL for parent_id since you didn't mean to say unknown, instead you meant none or 0.

Answer (score 2):

Unique index does not restrict a number of rows with NULL.

Use a real value, e.g. 0 instead of NULL or remove nullable fields from the index.

Comment: So basically any column which can be NULL is making the index ineffective?

Comment: Only for rows with NULLs, if a row doesn't have NULLs, it can't be duplicated

Comment: Any column, or just columns included in index cannot be NULL?

Comment: Also this answer disagrees with you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346765/unique-constraint-that-allows-empty-values-in-mysql