# Django Model Unique Constraint Exception

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model that has a unique together constraint, but I need a specific instance to be able to be repeated over and over. Is this possible?

```
name = models.ForeignKey(name)
time = models.BigIntegerField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = ("name", "time",)
```

I'm trying to get time=0 and for the same user multiple times. However, in every other instance it time needs to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `unique_together` field is validated on database level (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together)). It is therefore not possible to make exceptions.

A solution could be to set time = null instead of time = 0. 
Your database backend needs to support unique constraint that allows empty values ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346765/unique-constraint-that-allows-empty-values-in-mysql)). This is supported by most major DBMS, but not all.

If you database does not support it you'll have to write a custom form validation.