# Using validate_uniqueness in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have added another login filled in devise, i.e. contact_no. Either email address or contact no. should provided. To make contact_no unique I added a check in my user model for uniquness.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :contact_no, allow_nil: true, allow_blank: true
```

But, it keeps throwing error

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_contact_no':
```

Comment: Try removing `allow_nil: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `allow_blank: true`

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1346776/4466467)

MySql unique index allows multiple NULL values(if column is NULLable), however in your case, you have `allow_blank` set to true, which results in multiple empty strings `""` inserted to table, which is causing that error

You can fix this by removing `allow_blank: true` and manually setting contact_no to `nil` when its blank

For ex:

```
# user.rb  
after_initialize :set_default, unless: persisted?

def set_default
   self.contact_no = nil if contact_no.nil? || contact_no.blank?
end
```

Comment: Yes! I was bit confused with `allow_nil`

Comment: Okay. I will try that and get back to you.